# Eclipse cdt: Includes header file correct, compiles, but highlights source code: "Unresolved inclusion"

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I have a project that uses a shared library from another project. 
In project settings I put the correct include paths and library for the GCC and G++ compiler (-L and -l option). It all compiles well, no problems here.
But the source code is not analyzed correctly. 
My included headerfile (that is located in the other project) is marked as "Unresolved inclusion and everywhere I use something from it, the source is highlighted as well.

```
#include "myHeader.h"
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The one that you are missing here (probably) is, telling the indexer where to look for those headers.
I normally manage my own Makefile, so I do not know how to make it work for both the eclipse managed makefile and for the Indexer. Probably you will find that the solution below will fix both.

On the solution; **right click on the project** in the Project explorer ( or resource explorer ), and **select Properties**. Now under "**C/C++ General**" > "**Paths and Symbols**", click on **Includes tab** and **select "GNU C++"**. Then on the right side, **you can add various include paths** ( similar to the -I option on gcc/g++ ) by clicking on **"Add..."** button.

Once you apply and click OK, the indexer will take a while to clear those unresolved object.

Answer (score 1):

A header should be included like this

```
#include "myHeader.h"
```

or if it's a standard lib header:

```
#include <string>
```

everything else is invalid.

Comment: Sorry. Corrected that. Still, it says unresolved inclusion but compiles just fine.

Comment: Worked for me - or kept osicllating between unresolved inclusion and this other error on duplicate path inclusion

Answer (score 0):

Remember to enable the **Providers** in the **"Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc."**.